# Batch : error during move

Tags: batch-file

I try to move file from folder1 to folder2 into loop.
But sometimes, files do not move and Error level tests equals 0 into loop.

```
FOR %%f IN (%folder%\*.txt) DO (
        call :loop %%~nxf
)

call .......

:loop
call XXX
if [%errorlevel%] == [0] (
    move /Y %1 %folder2%
    echo %errorlevel%
)
```

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

FOR %%f IN (%folder%\*.txt) DO (
  move /Y %%f %folder2%
  if !errorlevel!==1 echo Error moving [%%f])
```